# Windows client powershell reporting

Tags: group-policy, powershell, scheduled-task, reporting

I'm working on trying to find a way to get our windows machines to report to a webpage with information about it's MAC address, computer name, currently logged in user, and ip address. I wrote a powershell script and set it up as a scheduled task. It works great but there is a window that appears every time the script runs. Is there a way to not show the window. I've tried running with "-noninteractive", "-nologo", "-windowstyle hidden", "-noprofile", all to no avail. This is what I use to run it.

"powershell.exe -noninteractive -nologo -windowstyle hidden -command "C:\Users\%LogonUser%\Scripts\CallHome.ps1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the script to a folder in the C: root and then running the script as the SYSTEM user. It grabs the currently logged on users when it runs so I no longer need it to run as those users. Been working great since I got it working and my inventory is building itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think of two possibilities which you can try:

1. Create a service user which has the user right to run batch jobs and log on as a service, schedule the task as that user wether it is logged on or not. This works and I use it frequently.
2. Use the start-process cmdlet. I believe it is capable of doing what you want but can't test myself right now (on iphone).

Comment: I like that you suggested a user with limited permissions instead of just running the scheduled task as SYSTEM.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check `Run whether user is logged on or not` on the General tab of the task properties. In this mode the program is started hidden.

A problem could be that you have to specify the user's password when setting up the task.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it like this:

```
start "" %systemroot%\System32\windowspowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -exec bypass -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -file "C:\Users\%LogonUser%\Scripts\CallHome.ps1"
```